# Open XML move sheets in workbook

Tags: c#, excel-2010, openxml-sdk

Using OpenXml on a excel sheet i create new worksheet.

```
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() 
{ Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
                                  workBookSheets.Append(sheet);
```

How do i move this newly created worksheet in the place of a another worksheet ?

For example :There are three worksheets
A,B,C and i create a new worksheet **A1** and want **A1** to be in the place of B . How do i go about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.InsertBefore(sheet, sheetB);
```

Where "sheetB" would be the OpenXMLElement. So rather than appending the sheet to the workbook you would insert sheet A1 before sheet B.

I was able to make a sheet the first in the workbook by doing the following:

```
document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.InsertBefore(sheet,
document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild);
```